# Override SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Does anyone know how to override SaveChangesAsync? I know a similar question was posted but there was no answer. I have the following code below:

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    PerformFurtherValidations();
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

During Build I get the following error message:

> Error SaveChangesAsync(): return type must be
>   `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>` to match overridden member
>   `System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`

Comment: I've just compiled the same code using EF 6.1.1 and didn't get any Build errors. Which version are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'm using the same EF version as yours. Spent 3.5 hours trying to resolve it. At the end all I had to do was close VS2013, restart it and voila, it works!

Answer (score 20):

- EF 6 (not EF Core 6):

  - The `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` method has two separate `virtual` overloads:

    1. `SaveChangesAsync()`
    2. `SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken)`.
  - By default, the parameterless `SaveChangesAsync()` overload simply calls into `SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken)` by passing `CancellationToken.None)`.
  - So by default you only need to override the `SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken)` overload.
  - However, if you want to be *absolutely certain* you should override `SaveChangesAsync()` *and* make it `sealed`, so any *further* subclasses of your `DbContext` have an unambiguous single method to overload.
- EF Core 5:

  - The `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` method has two separate `virtual` overloads, but they have different signatures compared to the older EF 6.

    - The main difference is that `cancellationToken` is now an optional parameter in all overloads.

    1. `SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)`
    2. `SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)`.

---

When overloading `async` methods be aware that:

- You will likely need to add the `async` modifier, otherwise you cannot use the `await` operator.
- When using Visual Studio's method stub generator (when you use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button after typing `override` to auto-insert the stub) it will lack the `async` modifier.
- However if your overload will just "forward" to another async method or the `base` implementation then you can simply do `return base.MyMethodAsync()`, however **never** do this if the method needs to do *something* in-between the other method returning and your override method returning.

  - I expect the most common case for this is when you need a `using` or `try` block to dispose of resources *only after* the other method completes, but if you don't use `await` inside the `using` block then the `.Dispose` method will be called *before* the `Task` completes.
- And don't forget to always add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to all `await` statements (unless you *absolutely* know what you're doing w.r.t the synchronization context).

---

### EF 6:

```
// This method is sealed and forwards to `SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken)`, so any further subclasses only need to override a single `SaveChangesAsync` method instead of 2.
// Also note it lacks the `async` modifier, so you cannot use the `await` operator.
public sealed override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    return this.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}

// This method has the `async` modifier, so `await` can be used:
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

### EF Core 5:

```
public sealed override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    return this.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess: true, cancellationToken);
}

public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: In this case, you should not await the base operation and just return the task without awaitig it. This may lead to deadlocks when calling from UI thread and waiting for the result.

Comment: Please provide some explanation around your solution, rather than just dumping code

Comment: @Matyas I don't think there's any difference when it comes to execution. What is your source?

Comment: @Javid There are many differences - though for trivial cases like this the only real difference is in exception handling _and_ that it will resume on the default synchronization context. See  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-performance-characteristics-of-async-methods/ and https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-asyncawait-over-directly-returning-task . Note that some people strongly advocate **always** using `await` to ensure consistent exception handling behaviour (which is what David Fowler recommends).

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the information. That comment is kinda old. At that time I didn't know the difference, now I do :)

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but I had a similar problem and resolved it with the following code:

```
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        foreach (var history in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(e => e.Entity is IModificationHistory && (e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                e.State == EntityState.Modified))
            .Select(e => e.Entity as IModificationHistory)
            )
        {
            history.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
            if (history.DateCreated <= DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                history.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
        int result = await base.SaveChangesAsync();
        foreach (var history in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                        .Where(e => e.Entity is IModificationHistory)
                                        .Select(e => e.Entity as IModificationHistory))
        {
            history.IsDirty = false;
        }
        return  result;
    }
```

The custom SaveChangesAsync() allows me to tweak the dirty flag, date created and date modified.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to return the task to the caller, you don't need to call an async method inside your version of SaveChanges, just omit "await" and "async" keywords:

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    PerformFurtherValidations();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and the root cause was that the EntityFramework reference to the project was from

> \packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\lib\net40

folder instead of

> \packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\lib\net45